# Archive subsites from sites in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, archive

I have a requirement to find a way to archive subsites from a site.

When I say 'Archiving' I mean moving a subsite from one site to another so the end users can still access the subsites and check the history etc.

The main site is a Training site and the subsites are training courses, when these courses have ran there is no need for them to be sat under the training department site and I can envision it becoming confusing with too many of these subsites.

I know I can move them using structure and content in site admin but don't really want end users to be doing that after each course has ran ( we have had over 500 this year!)

Has anyone else faced a similar issue or have any advice to how they would go about it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a need to retain the subsites? If so, instead of moving the site, perhaps changing the way your users access the sites would be an easier way. You could set up a list with the current classes (assuming you don't have one already) and include a field in that list that links to the course's subsite.  Create a view that shows only the current courses so the end users never see the other subsites.

If you don't need to keep the subsites, you should look into some kind of workflow that can kick off when a class expires that deltes the subsite.  I'm pretty sure you can't create a workflow with Nintex or SharePoint Designer to move a site to another location, so you may need to code something with C#.